# Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to make a chat on flutter + firebase. I have never worked with firebase. I created a project and databases via Google console, configured everything according to the instructions from there. An error appears at startup:

> W/PersistentConnection(11067): pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://my-testing-project-1020a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

Here is the full source:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();    
    runApp(MyApp());
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('сhats');
  final _txtCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My chat')),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: _firebaseRef.onValue,
                    builder: (context, snap) {
                      print(snap);

                      if (snap.hasData && !snap.hasError) {
                        final event = snap.data as Event;
                        Map data = event.snapshot.value;

                        List item = [];

                        data.forEach((index, data) => item.add({"key": index, ...data}));

                        return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: item.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(item[index]['message']),
                              trailing: Text(DateFormat("hh:mm:ss")
                                  .format(DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(item[index]['timestamp'] * 1000))
                                  .toString()),
                              onTap: () => updateTimeStamp(item[index]['key']),
                              onLongPress: () => deleteMessage(item[index]['key']),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text('No data');
                      }
                    }
                  ),
                ),
                Container(child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: TextField(controller: _txtCtrl)),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 80,
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      child: Text("Add", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
                      onPressed: () => sendMessage()
                    ),
                  )
                ]))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    _firebaseRef.push().set({
      "message": _txtCtrl.text,
      "timestamp": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
    });
  }

  updateTimeStamp(key) {
    _firebaseRef.child(key).update({"timestamp": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch});
  }

  deleteMessage(key) {
    _firebaseRef.child(key).remove();
  }
}
```

---

[image: google-services.json]

And it also outputs such errors too:

```
W/DynamiteModule( 2551): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 2551): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 2551): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 2551): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
```

Comment: If you get an error message, please always search for that error message first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bflutter%5D++Database+lives+in+a+different+region.+Please+change+your+database+URL+to

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found these questions, but it didn't help me!

Comment: Did you try specifying your database URL in the code (as the linked question suggests)? `final _firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "https://my-testing-project-1020a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").reference().child('сhats');` If so, edit your question to show what you tried please.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I set it in google-services.json: https://goo-gl.me/wHqj1

Comment: The common cause of this problem is that it's not being picked up correctly from the config file, which is why I asked you to put the URL in the code in my previous comment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added. Reopen please...

Comment: Did you already try putting the URL in the code, as I suggested? Did that change the logging output from the app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried. No.

Comment: It seems quite unlikely that the same log output is given when you hard-code the correct URL. Can you edit your question and add at the bottom the code you now use to access the database and the log output you now get?

Comment: Had same problem. Replaced google-services.json. That was not enough. ```flutter clean``` and ```flutter pub get``` worked